# Strange errors in someones Android Studio project (Manifiest.xml,etc)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I should compile someone's source code in the last Android Studio.
I have set SDK to 5.0.1 as required.
I see the following:

[image]

I did:
"File > Project Structure > Modules", click "add" and then click "android",  "apply/ok".

All line became normal instead of lines such as

```
<receiver
        android:name="ru.crmsensor.client.core.BootCompletedReceiver"
```

I exclude ".idea" from paths such as "D:\CRM\CRM3b.idea\AndroidManifest.xml"
in File > Project Structure > Modules> Android>paths,
then again a lot of red lines in manifest,
but I could create signed APK.

I can't install this APK by ADB no or device or Emulator
because of error
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES 
As i understand it happens because APK is unsigned.
But I've create signed APK!
Miracles...
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing as module then just goto file->new->import module.

Once you have imported, add it as dependency in your app's build.gradle like *compile project(':yourModule')*

Sync your gradle and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, but my employer said that I should not use gradle. He said that that the project will not work with gradle

Comment: Your employer, like many employers, does not know what he is talking about.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved the problem. I clones the project from bitbucket by "hg clone", then opened existing project in Studio, When I cloned it in Studio, all is okay.